# How to determine if I have not selected any item at combobox? c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Month_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (Month.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!");
            }
            else
            {
                Month.Text = Month.SelectedText;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to popup some messagebox to show that they haven't selected any items from the list and prevent it from inserting do my data.
For example I have a list of the months but they didn't select any on the list instead they typed "Janary" which is typo, that's the time the messagebox will prompt.
Thanks!
C# WINFORMS

Comment: If you don't want your users choose something different from the items that you have provided then set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList.

Comment: Use `if(Month.SelectedItem != null)`

Comment: Or if (Month.SelectedIndex != -1)

Comment: It is a no-win scenario. Your users are allowed to type texts that you are not willing to accept. To fix the problem you need to write code that blocks your user from typing invalid text. So why all this effort? Last time I have checked months are just 12 strings.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just follow your advice then. :D